# I am trying to use text choices and I receive this erro - python 'appstat' cannot be converted to a MySQL type", None

Tags: django, model

I receive this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError:(-1, "Failed processing format-parameters; P)
```

Here is the models.py where the error originates:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    class AppStat(models.TextChoices):
        Submitted = 'SUB', ('Submitted')
        HRREV = 'HR', ('HR Reviewed')
        Contacted = 'CON', ('Contacted')
        Accepted = 'AC', ('Accepted')
        Rejected= 'REJ', ('Rejected')
```

It works fine in a local environment, but it doesn't when I move to an environment in a docker container using mysql connector.

```
Exception Value:    
(-1, "Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'appstat' cannot be converted to a MySQL type", None)
```